# I need to find a way to show the number of relationships between values in two different excel columns

Tags: excel-formula

OK, I have two columns in excel that contain city names. I need a rank of how many times a relationship between two cities occurs. For example, the ranking for the data below should be as follows. #1 is Austin to Dallas with 3 occurrences. #2 is Chicago to Boston with 2 occurrences. #3 is Chicago to New York with 1 occurrence.

[sample data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3M7B.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a =COUNTIFS statement to check specific cities.

For example:

Row 1 = Headers

Column A = Origin City

Column B = Destination City

Data in your table should be in A2:B7

You can use:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,"Austin",$B$2:$B$7,"Dallas")
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,"Chicago",$B$2:$B$7,"Boston")
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,"Chicago",$B$2:$B$7,"New York")
```

Comment: This answer tells us only the count and not the rank #1, #2 and so on....

Comment: The Problem with that is that the city names are always changing. I need a formula that works no matter what set of city names are pasted in

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'll see if I can work on finding you a new answer later today.